# How to pickle complex enum values in Python

Tags: python, enums, pickle

When I try to unpickle pickled complex enum instance, I always get "ValueError: BLUE is not a valid Colors".

Is there any way how to pickle and unpickle?

```
from pickle import loads, dumps
from enum import Enum


class ColorType(object):

    def __init__(self, counter, name):
        self.counter = counter
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Colors(Enum):
    GREEN = ColorType(1, 'GREEN')
    BLUE = ColorType(2, 'BLUE')


color = Colors.BLUE
print(color is loads(dumps(color)))
```

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Presumably you are using the `enum34` backport package then?

Comment: And why are you using a `ColorType` class? IIRC `Enum` has support for more complex value types directly including additional methods, without using a separate class object. See the documentation for examples.

Comment: yes, I have `enum34` installed, This example is just to illustrate the real problem that is much more complex.

Comment: So why not use the setup as shown in the [Planet example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet)?

Comment: Besides, the name is already set for each of those objects; you can safely use `GREEN = 1` and `Colors.GREEN.name` will produce `'GREEN'`. I'm afraid you are using enum in a way that is incompatible with the pickle support.

Comment: I agree with @MartijnPieters that you should put whatever functionality you need directly in the `Enum` class; however, if you do need to mix-in another class you can -- just make sure and set `__eq__` and `__ne__` so unpickling works.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43764213/208880) for details.

Comment: beware that pickling/unpickling enums between processes seems to cause trouble. Pickled enum carries over the object id which clashes with the enum object id in the deserializing process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use a custom class as the enum values; there is no need here.  Your specific example doesn't need a separate class at all, you could just use:

```
class Colors(Enum):
    GREEN = 1
    BLUE = 2

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def counter(self):
        return self.value
```

This has *better* `str()` and `.counter` behaviour; your code requires `str()` to be applied to `Color.<name>.value` rather than directly to `Color.<name>`.

For other custom methods and attributes, put those directly on the `Enum` subclass and they'll be part of the enum members too. If you need more values per entry, set a *tuple* and pull that tuple apart in a `__init__` method. The documentation has an excellent [Planet example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet) that illustrates this further.

Demo:

```
>>> Colors.BLUE
<Colors.BLUE: 2>
>>> Colors.BLUE.value
2
>>> Colors.BLUE.counter
2
>>> str(Colors.BLUE)
'BLUE'
>>> Colors.BLUE is loads(dumps(Colors.BLUE))
True
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I put my methods to `Colors` enum directly.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is basic equality:

```
>>> ColorType(2, 'BLUE') == ColorType(2, 'BLUE')
False
```

So when `Colors` is trying to find a match for the unpickled value of `ColorType(2, 'BLUE')` it is failing.

The solution is simple:  add the `__eq__` and `__ne__` methods to `ColorType':

```
class ColorType(object):

    def __init__(self, counter, name):
        self.counter = counter
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name and self.counter == other.counter

    def __ne__(self, other):
        # not needed in Python 3
        return self.name != other .name or self.counter != other.counter
```

**NB** I agree with @MartijnPieters that in most cases you should just add the needed functionality to the `Enum` itself.

Comment: But why have the second class *in the first place*?

Comment: If not using `aenum` a simple way to get attribute access is to mix-in a `namedtuple`, for example; the point is it can be done should you need it.  (No, I have no use-cases myself.)

Comment: In Python 3, `__ne__` would be optional as there [`__ne__` delegates to `__eq__` and inverts the result](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__). Unfortunately, in Python 2 you are not so lucky.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in python3 and I found that the incompatibility between enum.Enum and pickle was because I was using enum.auto().

The solution was to put explicit fixed value on creation of my enum items and it solved the issue.

The reason is that enum.auto() generate an empty object which is unique, but it is identified only by its internal id (or its hash it is as you want) and from an execution to another, those id and hash and different, so, on a new execution of my app, pickle.load is unable to find the stored item in my enum class because the ids of the enum.auto() has changed.

I think that it is exacly the same issue for python2

Example :

use :

```
class Root_type(enum.Enum):
    no_scan = 0
    no_scan = 1
```

instead of :

```
class Root_type(enum.Enum):
    no_scan = seq.auto()
    no_scan = seq.auto()
```